# Correct way to make an ajax call from EmberJs component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

I would like to know what is the correct way to make an ajax call from an ember component. for example

I want to create a reusable component that makes an employee search by employee's Id, then when the response comes back from the server I want to update the model with the data from the ajax response.

I don´t know if this is the correct way to do it, I'm really new on emberjs.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
actions: {
    doSearch() {
        showLoadingData();
        var self = this;
        this.get('ajax').post('http://server.ip.com/api/v1/getEmployee', { "id": this }).then(function(data) {
            self.set('model.name', data.name);
            self.set('model.position', data.position);
            hideLoadingData();
        });
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I misunderstood the question, so here's an updated version of my answer:

First, I think you should switch to using ember-data. Then fetching an employee by id would just resolve to calling `this.get("store").find("employee", id)`.

If you wish to use plain ajax, I suggest that you create a [Service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/applications/services/) that encapsulates specifics (API endpoint URL, data format, and so on) and only exposes simple methods for finding and updating models.

And finally, to comply with the "data down, actions up" pattern, you shouldn't update the model in this component. Instead send an action to the parent controller/component. Like so:

`app/components/employee-selector.js` (the component you're writing):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    updateId(id) {
      Ember.$.post("http://server.ip.com/api/v1/getEmployee", { id: params.id }.then((response) => {
        this.sendAction("select", response);
    });
  }
});
```

`app/templates/new/it-request.hbs`:

```
{{employee-selector select=(action "selectEmployee")}}
```

`app/controllers/new/it-request.js`:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    selectEmployee(employeeData) {
      this.set("model.name", employeeData.name);
      this.set("model.position", employeeData.name);
    }
  }
});
```

Old answer:

An idiomatic solution would be to do this in a `Route`.

First you should add a route in `app/router.js`:

```
this.route("employees", function() {
  this.route("show", { path: ":id" });
}
```

Than define the route in `app/employees/show/route.js`:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) {
      Ember.$.post("http://server.ip.com/api/v1/getEmployee", { id: params.id }.then(
        (response) => { resolve(response) },
        reject
      );
    });
  }
});
```

(The only reason I wrapped everything in a new promise is to allow response customization - just replace `resolve(response)` with a code that transforms the raw response from the server and invoke `resolve` with this transformed version).

But if you'll have more communication with the API, and I suppose that you will, I suggest that you try using ember-data or any other data layer library for ember (probably Orbit).

Or at least write a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/applications/services/) that abstracts away all communication with the API and use it anywhere you'd use raw ajax requests.

Comment: but why should I create the route employees? what I want is to show a form that has a search box for the employee information and then continue to fill the form that has more fields and finally sumit that info to a server. all of this using the route new/it-request

Comment: OK, sorry, I misunderstood. In this case Component is OK, but still, I think that you should extract the ajax logic to a service or switch to ember-data.

Comment: And one more thing - this component probably shouldn't update the model by itself, but instead it should send an action with new employee data so that the parent component/controller can handle it and update the model accordingly.

Comment: Ok let me do some test and I would let you know the results

Comment: We were going to drop ember js in favor of other framework, because we couldn't create reusable components now we have a a universal component to make database catalog requests and a central Service to call and submit data for employees. the only question now about emberjs is how to handle form validations, in other system we develop we use jquery.validate but that is another question that I'll posting in a near future. meanwhile Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That's good to hear :)

There are some excellent validation addons for ember. The best at the moment are [ember-changeset-validations](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset-validations) and [ember-changeset](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset) however this is more than just validations.

I also encourage you to give my library a try, to simply create forms without repeating the same markup for each of the inputs over and over again: [Ember Form Builder](https://github.com/nibynic/ember-form-builder).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Ember class directly in action so it looked like this

```
actions: {
  doSomething() {
    Ember.$.post('http://your-api-endpoint', data).then(function(response){ /* your callback code */});  
  }
}
```

And other way to communicate with BE is to use Ember Store (as you said) then in route you can get model from BE

example

```
App.PressRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    route: "press",
    controllerName: 'press',
    model: function(params) {
        var controller = this.controllerFor("Press");

        if(controller.get("loaded") == false) {
            controller.set("loaded",true);
            return this.store.find('Article',{limit: 200});
        }
        else return this.store.all('Article');
    }, 
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('press');
    }
});
```

Comment: But is it ok to do it? as far I understand every ajax call must be done by a model and not by other mean. I am really confused with the model thing. I'm not sure if this is the way emberjs should work. Because let say I want to save data of the employee using a component via ajax, Is it ok to do it or I should do it using the model?

Comment: If you want to save model data then use store methods

store provides you various methods as FIND, ALL and others

Comment: The problem with the store is that all my back end services are on different servers for example. the employee data comes form http://sql.core.data/employees other data related to the employeee comes from http://webserver.apis.intranet/api/v1/getResources as far as I understand this involves creating for each model an adapter and a serializer, cause some data comes on soap format. Normally on jquery I created deferred calls but I'm not sure how to create this behavior on emberjs

Comment: maybe try to set empty host in adapter and use this method to modify urls for models 

import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return Ember.String.underscore(type);
  }
});

you can make some kind of switch in there

Comment: I tried using JSONAPIAdapter and it does not work so instead of that I use DS.Adapter, but Do i need to create for every model the same adapter I mean some data change but the request to the end point is the same. for example my Model Employee (id,name,depto,title) needs info from http://sql.core.data/employees  but my Model Supervisor need the same data as employee but with two more attributes (dtoId, active) I try to use inheritance but the request to the server get really messy and does not work as I would expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this!

Firstly, Ember has a convient [alias](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/jquery/methods/$?anchor=%24) for jQuery: `Ember.$`. So, if you're familiar jQuery, this should be easy enough.

You can also use Ember's [RSVP](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/modules/rsvp) package. There's a [good example here](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/Promise) on how to make a request and do something with the response.

Thirdly, you can the [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax) service.

But what you're asking (update the model with the data from the ajax response) is already built into Ember Data. You'll need to map your API into what ember expects with an adapter and/or a serializer. Once your service is transformed into what Ember expects, you can [query your server for a single record](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/finding-records/) then save it.