# How to get the return state from a sendAction method in a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am not using Ember Data (I do not know if it solves the issue). I have a component and click the button will invoke an external event handler defined inside the controller. I would like to know the return state from a `sendAction` method. See image below for details.

[image]

1. enter text in textarea
2. click "BTN SAVE"
3. handle action in `index` controller
4. perform ajax request in `btnPressed` actions obj
5. **MY QUESTION** How to notify the component the return state from the step (4)

Once I know the request state I can perform the correspond action(s) in my component.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have return value from action if you're using old action handling mechanism(using sendAction()), what you need are closure actions. Using closure actions you can call action defined in controller directly in component and have return value from it. 
Here's your example using closure actions.

```
index.hbs
{{note-editor btnPressed=(action 'btnPressed')}}
```

In note-editor.hbs

```
<button onclick={{action 'actionBtnPressed'}}>Save</button>
```

And then in note-editor.js you can call btnPressed when button is clicked.

```
actionBtnPressed() {
   let val = this.btnPressed();
   // val is value returned from controller's btnPressed action
}
```

You can read more about closure actions here.
https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0050-improved-actions.md

Answer (score 0):

After reading the post [Correct way to make an ajax call from EmberJs component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758799/correct-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-from-emberjs-component),

I move the AJAX code inside the controller to the component to solve this issue.

```
    actionBtnPressed() {
        const card = {
            front: this.get('cardFront'),
            back: this.get('cardBack'),
            tags: this.get('tags')
        };

        if (this._validateCardFront()) {
            this.get('ajax').createCard(card)
                .done((data) => {
                    this._cleanInputs();
                })
                .fail((err) => {
                });
        }
    }
```

`ajax` is a service that is injected into the component.